Using run_login() on a P4 instance inside Docker container updates the tickets file but does not update the value of the password on the instance
For some reason, when I use the run_login() method on a connected P4 instance inside of the Docker container, it correctly updates the ticket file, but the value stored on the instance does not get updated which causes subsequent commands that require a valid ticket to fail (e.g. p4.run_fstat(). I have confirmed that doing the same exact thing works correctly outside of the container (meaning, the ticket file updates and that value is stored in the password attribute correctly).

Inside the Docker container, I have set the following P4 env vars (I have confirmed they are all working correctly):

P4CONFIG
P4TRUST
P4TICKETS


After running p4.run_login(), if I manually change the value of p4.password to the value stored in the updated ticket file, p4.run_fstat() works as expected.
When I do the same thing on my laptop directly, the value of p4.password is updated to the ticket value automatically.
I have confirmed that the version of p4python and Python are the same both inside and outside of the container.

(----) bash-4.4# python
Python 3.12.5 (main, Aug 14 2024, 05:08:31) [Clang 18.1.8 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import P4
>>> p4 = P4.P4()
>>> p4.password
'<P4CONFIG defined password>'
>>> p4.connect()
P4 [----] connected
>>> p4.run_login()
[{'User': '----', 'TicketExpiration': '----'}]
>>> p4.password
'<P4CONFIG defined password>'
>>> p4.run_fstat("//barf")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 530, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self.run(cmd, *args, **kargs)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 647, in run
    raise e
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 641, in run
    result = P4API.P4Adapter.run(self, *flatArgs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
P4.P4Exception: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
>>> p4.run_fstat("//valid/depot/path.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 530, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self.run(cmd, *args, **kargs)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 647, in run
    raise e
  File "/----/lib/python3.12/site-packages/P4.py", line 641, in run
    result = P4API.P4Adapter.run(self, *flatArgs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
P4.P4Exception: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
>>>


You don't need P4PASSWD and a ticket!  To avoid confusion, I'd remove P4PASSWD from your P4CONFIG file.  It sounds like you have a valid ticket if p4 login is returning a success.

So, in order to generate the p4tickets file, I need to have the password set so that I can run p4.run_login(). After that, as you mentioned, if I get rid of the P4PASSWD line in the P4CONFIG file, I am able to run p4.run_fstat() properly, and the p4.password attribute updates as expected. I am still unclear why it is behaving differently inside vs outside of docker.

That's harder to answer, but I expect if you dig into it with p4 set you'll find some subtle environmental difference.
